# Why Avira Antivirus Cannot Read some .chm Files?

Tags: windows-10, avira

Warning in Windows 10 Education edition

> C:\Users\masi\document.chm
>   [WARNING] The file could not be read!

I would like to understand why Avira cannot read the file, documents are mostly .chm files. I can read them still in my system.

---

Why Avira Antivirus cannot read some .chm files in your system?

Comment: Not anymore too broad. There should be an explanation why Avira cannot do it, but my OS can.

Comment: In order for Avira to read a .chm that capability must be programmed into the software.  Windows can read .chm files because that capability has been aded to Windows.  We cannot tell you the specific reason, Avira does not have this capability, we didn't write the software.  **You should ask the company who wrote Avira for that reason**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of software, drivers and firmware are yet to be properly updated for full compatibility with Windows 10.  Until Avira comes out with an appropriate update or new version of the software you can expect to see some issues like this.

If this is a serious issue for you, you could try contacting Avira for information on upcoming updates.

Information here indicates that many consumer versions of Avira will not be compatible with Windows 10 - https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-business-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1777 - perhaps best to find a more compatible piece of software.

EDIT:  This answer is based on my experience of upgrading windows 7 and 8.1 systems with Avira installed to Windows 10.  Whilst I did not see the specific error the user is reporting, I found that Avira demonstrated some incompatibility with Windows 10 (at least from an Upgrade to Windows 10 where Avira was installed in the previous version).  Avira states that consumer versions of Avira Antivirus are not compatible with Windows 10, as can be seen from the link above.

Comment: The user's problem has less to do with Windows 10 then Avira simply cannot process .CHM files.  Much the same way other security software cannot scan the files within a .Zip archive, that compatability, must be programmed by the author of the security software.

Comment: @ Ramhound True.  My response was based on an assumption that the system had been upgraded to Windows 10 from an earlier version and still had the Avira software installed from the previous version.  If this was not the case, and if Avira also cannot read these files in earlier versions of Windows, then I retract my answer.